# How to select Photo from Gallery in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

In my project, I need to apply action for the user to select the profile photo.

Normally, I can successfully complete this process by applying intent in the fragment, but I think I should do the logic part in the viewmodel.

Thank you.

How to select photos in View model.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

use data-binding for your layout

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

use interface to communicate between ViewModel and activity only for UI interaction like onClick, OnLongClick

check [this](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture) open source github project they developed sample app using mvvm with clean architecture